# Android xml changes order of special chars?

Tags: android, xml, special-characters

```
     <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:text="&#x2500; 23"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textSize="9sp" />
```

will results

```
    23 ─
```

instead of expecting

```
    ─ 23
```

why?

Comment: It's working for me. Did you previously have them switched? Perhaps the resources are not being refreshed properly by your IDE?

Comment: Should be the prob, will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some eclipse problem between graphical layout and xml editor.

[image: how the error looks like]